# How to implement JsonPatch in .NET Core 3.0 Preview 9 correctly?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to implement JsonPatch on .NET Core 3.0 Preview 9 web api.

The model:

```
public class TestPatch
{
    public string TestPath { get; set; }
}
```

The web api endpoint:

```
[HttpPatch()]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<TestPatch> patch)
{
   ...........
   return Ok();
}
```

The JSON payload:

```
[
    {
        "op" : "replace",
        "path" : "/testPath",
        "value" : "new value"
    }
]
```

Using PATCH via Postman, I got this error:

```
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "|492c592-4f7de4d16a32b942.",
"errors": {
    "$": [
        "The JSON value could not be converted to Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.JsonPatchDocument`1[Test.Models.TestPatch]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
    ]
}
}
```

Here's the complete request/response from Postman

```
PATCH /api/helptemplates HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.16.3
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: a41813ea-14db-4664-98fb-ee30511707bc
Host: localhost:5002
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 77
Connection: keep-alive
[
{
"op" : "replace",
"path" : "/testPath",
"value" : "new value"
}
]
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 12 Sep 2019 21:13:08 GMT
Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|492c593-4f7de4d16a32b942.","errors":{"$":["The JSON value could not be converted to Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.JsonPatchDocument`1[Test.Models.TestPatch]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."]}}
```

JsonPatch Reference:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="3.0.0-preview9.19424.4" />
```

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Posted an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13938 and it was resolved by using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.

Answer (score 12):

Support for `JsonPatch` is enabled using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package. To enable this feature, apps must:

- Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` NuGet package.
- Update the project's `Startup.ConfigureServices` method to include a
  call to `AddNewtonsoftJson`

```cs
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

`AddNewtonsoftJson` is compatible with the MVC service registration methods:

- `AddRazorPages`
- `AddControllersWithViews`
- `AddControllers`

But if you are using **`asp.net core 3.x`**, then

`AddNewtonsoftJson` replaces the `System.Text.Json` based input and output formatters used for formatting **all** JSON content. To add support for `JsonPatch` using `Newtonsoft.Json`, while leaving the other formatters unchanged, update the project's `Startup.ConfigureServices` as follows:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, GetJsonPatchInputFormatter());
    });
}

private static NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter GetJsonPatchInputFormatter()
{
    var builder = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddLogging()
        .AddMvc()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson()
        .Services.BuildServiceProvider();

    return builder
        .GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>()
        .Value
        .InputFormatters
        .OfType<NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter>()
        .First();
}
```

The preceding code requires a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` and the following using statements:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Linq;
```

A brief explanation and documentation for the above can be found in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.0#jsonpatch-addnewtonsoftjson-and-systemtextjson)

Comment: This solution works, but I have a small issue. I have a OutputFormatters set XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter to support XML responses. After your code change all the requests have to explicitly mention the Accept header with application/json. Otherwise XML is returned by default. How do I set Json as the default output formatted?

Comment: services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                .AddMvcOptions(o =>
                {
                    o.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
                    o.InputFormatters.Insert(0, GetJsonPatchInputFormatter());
                }).AddNewtonsoftJson();

Comment: That is because of the order of your configuration. You need to add `services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsodtJson().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters`. Refer my  [EnterpriseArchitecture](https://github.com/fingers10/EnterpriseArchitecture/blob/008617be8273103814c8fa5f537e9080153c6ccf/API/Startup.cs#L68-L96) repository for reference. You need to swap the order of registering output formatters. In `Asp.Net Core 3.1` you can just add `AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters`. Please remove `XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter` from `AddMvcOptions`

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for the late upvote :)

Comment: Note: as of now, the documentation is incomplete. If you use `System.Text.Json` with your API but `NewtonSoft.Json` for JSON PATCH documents, the client must send the `Content-Type` `application/json-patch+json` instead of `application/json` otherwise it doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

This answer is for 3.1, but I think it applies to 3.0 as well....
The default json parser in asp.net core 3.x isn't as complete as NewtonsoftJson, so use it until Microsoft implements a feature.

Add this nuget package to your project:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson

Then add this using statement in startup.cs:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
```

...
Then change your ConfigureService() to include the NewtonsoftJson formatter in startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(setupAction =>
    setupAction.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true
   ).AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters().AddNewtonsoftJson(setupAction =>
   setupAction.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
   //...
}
```

You may also have to add Accept set to application/json to your requests to prevent them returning XML.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

For those using .NET Core 6.0:

Add the Nuget package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson to your project

Then add this using statement to your Program.cs:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
```

Finally add this code to your Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
}).AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```